# ng-click not working with menu dynamic AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, menu, angularjs-ng-click

I have a menu that is populated dynamically:

```
<div ng-controller="menuDinamicoController as vm">
  <div ng-show="isAutenticado">
     <img src="{{vm.fotoUser}}" id="imagemUsuario" width="50px" />
     <label id="nomeUsuario" ng-model="nomeUser">{{vm.nomeUser}}</label>
    <div id="menu">
       <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="x in menu">
            <a href="{{x.Link}}" ng-click="vm.{{x.Id}}()">{{x.Nome}}</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The structure of the link is being returned correctly:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="vm.sair()" class="ng-binding">Sair</a>
```

The controller has the following function:

```
vm.sair = function () {
    $cookieStore.remove("Usuario");
    $cookieStore.remove("Token");
    $location.path("/");
};
```

However, the ng-click isn't calling the function. And get the following error: ***Syntax Error: Token 'x.Id' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not really need interpolation `{{ }}` inside the `ng-click` attribute.

If `x.Id` is a dynamically created function you should use the `[]` syntax instead:

```
ng-click="vm[x.Id]()"
```

To help further, please provide an example (with snippet, jsbin, or plunker).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[]` object notation when passing variables as object keys in javascript. Also since you are passing as veriable, don't use expression around the variable

Try:

```
<a href="{{x.Link}}" ng-click="vm[x.Id]()">{{x.Nome}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirement itself is so Weird..!!!!! YOu will never have such type of functions for ng-clicks''!!! Even if you, it is that you will have to create 100's of functions for 100 objects in the data???